# Simple self-contained SNMP Agent example? (java/c# ideal)

Tags: c#, .net, snmp, agent

After [not having a whole bunch of luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656587/implementing-an-snmp-reporter-in-c-must-run-on-mono) finding any SNMP libraries for .NET that can act as SNMP agents (that can be used in an OSS project - meaning proprietary libs are out), I am now looking at implementing a simple SNMP agent class in C#.

Can anyone provide any good examples or reference implementations of an SNMP agent (ideally nice & self contained), that I can use as a porting reference? Language isnt too important - but the simpler the better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My open source project #SNMP Suite has a tiny project named "TestAgent". It is a WinForms based small utility to test out very basic SNMP agent functionality. This is what I use to test out #SNMP MIB Browser.

It is far from mature. But if you like, it shows how to use #SNMP library to send and receive SNMP packets.

If you want to port something from other languages, snmp4j has a test agent too in Java.

http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com

Comment: Now this TestAgent sample grows up quickly. I have just made it an snmpd for v1. Will let it support v2 soon.

Comment: In #SNMP 4 release, we are able to cover most v2 support in snmpd (TestAgent). Now we are heading on to release 5.0, and try to deliver v3 support then.

Comment: Most SNMP v3 support is added to #SNMP Agent in Change Set 38958. We will release #SNMP 5 probably in May or June.

Comment: Hii Lex..you are not using the MIB's according to the RFC's standard..then ain't i voilate any rules of this protocol??..is it ok if i just process the request from the manager.??

Comment: Hi Divya, if you have any suggestion about how MIB documents should be used, feel free to start a conversation on http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/Thread/List.aspx