# C# SNMP Agent Command handler

Tags: c#, snmp

The current context is on one side I have a system in which we have camera adaptors (that we develop) that helps us integrate cameras in the system. And on the other side we have a camera simulator.

In my camera adaptor, to get the current `UpTime` of the camera, I send an `SNMP Get` command with the correct Oid for `system UpTime`.

In my adaptor, I am using the `SnmpSharpNet library`.

```
public static void GetSystemUptime(string host, out TimeSpan? uptime)
{
   SimpleSnmp snmp = new SimpleSnmp();
   snmp.PeerIP = IPAddress.Parse(host);
   Oid oid = new Oid(SnmpOid.SYS_UPTIME);
   Dictionary<Oid, AsnType> dict = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver1, new[] { oid.ToString()});
   AsnType asnType;

   if (dict == null || dict.TryGetValue(oid, out asnType) == false || asnType == null || asnType.GetType() != typeof(TimeTicks))
   {
      uptime = null;
      return;
   }

   uptime = (TimeSpan)(asnType as TimeTicks);
}
```

But now, I'm working on the camera simulator which actually simulates cameras.  So I now need to make the `SNMP Agent`.
I can't seem to find information on how to handle `Get` commands in an SNMP Agent so I can afterwords reply the right information.

Can anyone link me to relevant information or guide me though the process.

Tanks,

Pat

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671225/simple-self-contained-snmp-agent-example-java-c-ideal

Comment: it's not obvious what's being asked. The code seems to be unrelated to the actual problem

Comment: The shown code is acutally my method to send a Get (working with real cameras).  Now I'm trying to actually be on the other side and handle this command.

Comment: @Les I've already looked at this, by I don't want to simply copy/paste code here and their, I want to understand the mechanic behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.lextm.com/2012/07/sharpsnmp-vs-snmpsharpnet/

What you asked is probably what every SNMP#NET users wonder.

SNMP#NET does not support agent development that well. You need to switch to another library, either commercial or open source.

Comment: Hi Lex, thanks for the answer, do you have any library in mind? I've been analysing and trying to understand the source of #SNMP suite from  the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671225/simple-self-contained-snmp-agent-example-java-c-ideal Any other library you would suggest (I'm looking for open source since it will only be used internaly)

Comment: If your development is limited to C#/.NET and you only consider open source solution, by far #SNMP is the only one option.

Comment: Hey Lex Li, I read though you #SNMP project, and found out that you OpenSource librairie is actually really good.  I would have 1-2 ideas for you, have any place where I could contact you.

Comment: As this is an open source project, you might post your ideas to the discussion board to collect feedback from all stakeholders. If you happen to have questions to me alone, you can send me a mail via CodePlex (Contact via http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/lextm).